# SimpleSamlPHP and Azure AD integration. Stuck in AADSTS50011 error

Tags: azure-active-directory, codeigniter-3, simplesamlphp

I can't seem to get past this error.  I am able to login into Microsoft, but after, that error shows up.  I have tried all set these reply URL's inside Azure, but still nothing:

- https://sso.xxxx.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp
- https://sso.xxxx.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp
- https://sso.xxxx.com/simplesaml
- https://sso.xxxx.com/

This is my simplesaml config file:

```
'baseurlpath' => 'https://sso.xxxx.com/simplesaml',
```

Here is my Authsource:

```
'default-sp' => [
    'saml:SP',
    'entityID' => 'xxxxxx-4521-4587-9b30-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'idp' => 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxx-f963-4bc4-98a8-xxxxxxxxxxxx/',
    'discoURL' => null,
    'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent',
    'simplesaml.nameidattribute' => 'eduPersonTargetedID',
```

Am I missing something in the config?  I test it via SimpleSamlPHP Test authentication sources:

```
https://sso.xxxx.com/simplesaml/module.php/core/authenticate.php?as=default-sp
```

and also via sourcecode in another website:

```
https://www.xxxx.com/nxsso/login
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue will occur when the redicrect_uri doesn't match the redirect uri in Azure portal.

You can use the fiddler to capture the auth request url, you will find the redirect_uri in the authorize endpoint. Then use this one in Azure portal.

The auth request url is something like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345
```

You will find the real `redirect_uri`.

**Update:** You should be able to find the request url before enter your username.

[image]

Comment: Hi tony, I cant seem to find a reference to that redirect_uri in when using Telerik Fiddler.  Though I sware that a bunch of reply URI's have been added in Azure.

Comment: @RayzorMamon You should be able to find the request url before enter your username. See the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: Hi @Tony Ju, sorry, lost track of this, but this is already fixed.  Aparently it started working after I created the Azure AD side SAML via Enterprise Applications > New Application > Non Gallery Application. Where you can configure the Return URL in it.